# 2014 Ford Fusion SE knocking noise

Tags: ford, noise, fusion

There has been this knocking noise coming from my left rear side/tire. I don’t remember exactly when it started but I can say it has to be about 3-4 months already. It started out as small noise but has gotten bigger over time. However, when I brake the noise stops. I don’t really know what to do. I would at least like to go in to a shop having somewhat of a knowledge regarding my issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That may well be a loose hub bearing, especially as you say the noise disappears on braking.

Take this in to be seen to ASAP as in the worst case you could loose the wheel...

Comment: Yup. Has happened to me once. Missing lug nuts, actually,  Ultimately found it was a missing lug nut (from a previous repair shop - which I make sure avoid - a national muffler chain). Very risky and I was lucky indeed . In hindsight it was   embarassing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible reasons for the noise, from the hub/wheel bearing mentioned above, to simple loose lug nuts.